# Working with HTTP-responses in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, httpresponse

I'm working on web-app with authorization via JWT and Angular 2. I've Nodejs/express server with API and client-side on Angular2.
So, my server answers GET request correctly and gives data like this:

`{
    "success": true,
    "user": {
        "_id": "5a6ef70edb04dd29e24bb03b",
        "email": "danko",
        "username": "ivan"
    }
}`

Next, here is my **auth.service.ts**. Functions *createAuthenticationHeaders() and getProfile()* takes part in handling HTTP responses:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http'; // Http, Headers, RequestOptions
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  domain = "http://localhost:8080";
  authToken;
  user;
  options;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private httplegacy: Http) {  }

  createAuthenticationHeaders() {
    this.loadToken();
    this.options = new RequestOptions({
      headers           : new Headers({
        'Content-Type'  : 'application/json',
        'authorization' : this.authToken
      })
    });
  }

  loadToken() {
    this.authToken  = localStorage.getItem('token');

  }

  registerUser(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.domain + '/authentication/register', user);
  }

  loginUser(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.domain + '/authentication/login', user);
  }


  storeUserData(token, user) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  getProfile() {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.httplegacy.get(this.domain + '/authentication/profile', this.options);
  }
}
```

Also, here is my **profile.component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  username;
  email;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService

  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      console.log(profile);
      this.username = profile.user.username;
      this.email    = profile.user.email;
    })

  }

}
```

Expected behavior of these lines of code: after handling server's response with user's data with **auth.service.t**s(mainly *createAuthenticationHeaders() and getProfile()* functions), user's data is transmitted to **profile.component.ts** to show it on web-page using next code:

```
<h2 class="page-header">Profile Page</h2>
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Username: {{ username }} </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Email: {{ email }}</li>
</ul>
```

But, while compiling I got an error: property 'user', doesn't exist on type 'Response'. Would You like to explain why i got such error, and how to fix it?

P.S.: yep, console.log(profile) gives me such info:

```
Response {_body: "{"success":true,"user":{"_id":"5a6ef70edb04dd29e24bb03b","email":"danko","username":"ivan"}}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
headers:Headers {_headers: Map(1), _normalizedNames: Map(1)}
ok :    true
status   :    200
statusText    :    "OK"
type    :    2
url    :    "http://localhost:8080/authentication/profile"
_body    :    "{"success":true,"user":{"_id":"5a6ef70edb04dd29e24bb03b","email":"danko","username":"ivan"}}"
__proto__    :    Body
constructor    :    ƒ Response(responseOptions)
toString    :    ƒ ()
__proto__    :
Object
```

But how can I get data from _body field of response?

P.S.: code for router from server side:

```
router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.decoded.userId }).select('username email').exec((err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: err });
        } else {
            if(!user) {
                res.json({ success: false, message: 'User not found'});
            } else{
                res.json({ success: true, user: user });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you try to read your `data` directly from the `Response` Object of `express`. You need smth like:

```
this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
  console.log(profile);
  let p = JSON.parse(profile._body)
  this.username = p.user.username;
  this.email    = p.user.email;
})
```

This will take the `JSON` string from the body of your `HTTP Response` and make it an accessible object.

**NOTE:**

It would be much better to tell the server to answer with a standard json due to this is web standard nowadays.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, to my regret. Same error: property 'body' doesn't exists on type 'response'

Comment: yes my initial answer has had an syntax error. try again, i already fixed it. You need to access `_body` instead of `body`

Comment: Same result, i already tried various combination like 'profile._body, response._body'

Comment: In my opinion, a better way to handle this would be to return JSON from the server in the first place. JSON is the standard now for REST services, and it avoids having to do stuff like JSON Parsing and it's just easier in my opinion. Plus, you areSENDING json to the server, it only makes sense to return json as well

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta yes in my opinion too but OP said nothing about any access to server source codes

Comment: Greetings, David! I create my program according to your MEAN-stack tutorial for Angular2. Maybe, you can help with it?

Comment: Seems like i've too little reputation to join chat.

Comment: @BJBlackovic only for private chats

Answer (score 0):

Update: @messerbill's was 50/50 correct. Such construction works:

```
this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
  console.log(profile);
  let p = JSON.parse(profile._body)
  this.username = p.user.username;
  this.email    = p.user.email;
})
```

My web-page got user's info and show it in correctly, but an error left and i've to comment these lines of code to compile and run my application, and uncomment after to see user's info on webpage. 
An error message: `property '_body' does not exists on type 'Response'`.
So, at this moment i've no idea how it works with an error and how to create **really** correct structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      console.log(profile);
      let p = profile.json();
      this.username = p.user.username;
      this.email    = p.user.email;
    })

  }
```

Comment: Nope, your code doesn't work - double initializing of variable 'profile'.

Comment: Sorry there was a code mistake. Check my updated answer.